# Code dynamic dropdown using Python, sqlite3, HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json, sqlite

I want to fetch userdata from sqlite DB table and list them as a dropdown list in my HTML code. I am new to Python. I tried writing a code, but it failed. list_fetched is my users list that I fetched from db table.

```
@app.route('/trail', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    list_tested = db_dropdown()
    return render_template("try.html", trail1=list_fetchted)


    return "hi"


try.html:

<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button type="submit" onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>
<script>
      var trail1 = {{ trail1|tojson }};
      function clicked()
      {
      alert("trail1[0]")
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No value is getting displayed.

Comment: Is this Flask?  Perhaps tag it so please.

Comment: You say you are new to Python, what programming languages have you used? (Just to get some reference points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the quick start guide for Flask, it may give some advice on your problem and help with your future learning. 
(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/)
I have a solution for your issue (I have removed any sqlite access but sure you can put that in):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template("try.html", trial1=['1', '2'])
```

Then your try.html file needs to be placed in /templates/try.html in your project directory. By default this is where Flask references templates.

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button type="submit" onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>
<script>
      var trail1 = {{ trial1|tojson }};
      function clicked()
      {
      alert(trail1[0])
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Enjoy learning python :)

Comment: the first element in the data that i fetched from db is '' blank. so alert function is not displaying anything. can you please help me how to create a drop down menu from the list fetched from db.